# Extract all DOI using regex - regex starting with a number and endning with a whitespace

Tags: regex

I have been trying to extract around 9000 DOIs from a large medline datafile. These identifiers are in the format "10.1*****/**************. " , always ending with a whitespace, thus start of string always "10.1" and ending with whitespace. I'm using the sublime text-editor.

My final goal is to remove everything else, thus I want a text file with newline for every DOI-code.

Extract from my data

```
    AID - 10.1111/acps.12913 [doi]
SO  - Acta Psychiatr Scand. 2018 Dec;138(6):492-499. doi: 10.1111/acps.12913. Epub 2018
LID - 10.1177/0284185118764209 [doi]
AID - 10.1177/0284185118764209 [doi]
SO  - Acta Radiol. 2018 Dec;59(12):1438-1445. doi: 10.1177/0284185118764209. Epub 2018 
LID - 10.1007/s00018-018-2873-1 [doi]
AID - 10.1007/s00018-018-2873-1 [doi]
SO  - Cell Mol Life Sci. 2018 Dec;75(23):4301-4319. doi: 10.1007/s00018-018-2873-1.
LID - 10.1097/EJA.0000000000000889 [doi]
AID - 10.1097/EJA.0000000000000889 [doi]
SO  - Eur J Anaesthesiol. 2018 Dec;35(12):949-954. doi: 10.1097/EJA.0000000000000889.
LID - 10.1097/CMR.0000000000000479 [doi]
AID - 10.1097/CMR.0000000000000479 [doi]
```

Thus, for "99. doi: 10.1111/acps.12913. Epub 2018" I want to keep "10.1111/acps.12913"

Thanks ahead!

Comment: What regex _tool_ are you actually using?

Comment: Sublime text editor, but I could use whatever would be most suiting!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can try doing this in two steps.  First, remove the lines which do not contain any DOIs:

```
Find: ^(?!.*10\.[A-Za-z0-9.\/-]+(?<!\.)(?=[ ]|\.)).*\n
Replace: (empty string)
```

Then do a replacement on the matching lines to leave behind just the DOIs:

```
Find:^.*(10\.[A-Za-z0-9.\/-]+)(?<!\.)(?=[ ]|\.).*$
Replace: $1
```

Here is a demo showing that the second pattern for making positive matches is working correctly.

### Demo

Comment: Thanks Tim, nearly worked, the 2nd step works for all DOIs containing a number after "/" but removes DOS containing letters.10.010
10.007
10.007
10.006
10.006
10.2340/00015555-2987
10.2340/00015555-2987
10.006
10.006
10.1177/2048872618805663
10.1177/2048872618805663

Comment: @TorstenDahlén I just updated the answer, it's tricky, but it seems to work now.